# Can't update data in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing problem updating new data in `mongodb` with `mongoose`.
Below is my code. It wasn't worth mentioning until my data was not updated even though it was actually affected and changed by `role.save()` (see in console.log).

```
        const updateRole = await Role.find({
          child_role: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: { $in: [body.name] },
            },
          },
        });
        for (const role of updateRole) {
          for (const child of role.child_role) {
            if (child.name === body.name) {
              child.status = false;
            }
          }
          // Save the role after updating the child status
          await role
            .save()
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result, 'result');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err, 'error saving role');
            });
        }
```

Have I done something wrong or misunderstood somewhere? Please let me know, I sincerely thank you.

I'm trying to find the records in the role collection that satisfy the request in child_role that contain my role, and update its status to false, but it's not updated at all.

Comment: you create new variable `child` and change value of `child.status` not value `status` of `role.child_role`. You can console `role.child_role` to see the value `status`. Updated to `role.child_role[i].sattus = false`

Comment: Can you post your schema please just to be clear how your documents are structured?

Comment: thank alot. i got it working just by adding: `role.markModified('child_role');`